# context.sendActivity sent from incoming part of middleware are not going through onSendActivities function

Tags: botframework

In middleware I am sending a few messages to the user on checking some conditions...

However these are not going through onSendActivities portion of the middleware... (with or without shortcircuiting.... ) i.e. calling next() all the time and skipping calling next() sometimes...

Is this a bug ? or built in by purpose.. Atleast expected all messages sent from incoming part of the middleware function to go through this function.

```js
  async onTurn( (context, next) => {
    //....
      await context.sendActivity(`whatever`)

      this.Bot.adapter.continueConversation(userRef, async turnContext => { 
           // the below one does not show up in console
           await turnContext.sendActivity(`Another message to user`); 
      })

     await context.onSendActivities( (sendContext, activities, sendNext) => {
       // expected both above sent to hit here...
        console.log(`activities : ${activities.map(a => a.text).join(',')}`)
       await sendNext()
     })
     await next()
  })
```

Comment: Documentation says "When the thread to process the activity is created, the list of handlers for that activity is copied to that new thread. No handlers added after that point will be executed for that specific activity event". So the sendActivity is not calling handlers when the sendActivity is called within the middleware or from proactive handlers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to cycle thru the `activities` object in the `onSendActivities()` method to log the activity. If you are looking to act on a particular activity, then you can parse each one looking for whichever flag or value you need to match on, then perform your action.

```js
await context.sendActivity(`whatever`);
await context.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, sendNext) => {
  for (let activity of activities) {
    console.log('SEND ACTIVITY ', activity);
  }
  return await sendNext();
});
```

Hope of help!

Comment: The activity is not reaching there... it reaches only if I send from rootDialog or outside of middleware. Not from within middleware.

Comment: Also, if sent proactively too they are not routed through middleware e.g. that.Bot.adapter.continueConversation(customerAdd, async turnContext => {
                                await turnContext.sendActivity(context.activity.text);
                            });

Comment: my bad. I was shortcircuiting the middleware on a specific condition.... not an issue